# converting nokogiri xml node into ruby hash

Tags: ruby, xml, hash, nokogiri

I have an xml like this

```
 <parentNode>

    <amount>12.0</amount><authIdCode>999999</ authIdCode><currency>USD</currency>

 </parentNode>
```

How can I get all nodes inside the ParentNode to a hash something like below?

```
{amount: "12", authIdCode: "999999", currency: "USD"}
```

Yes I could search for individual keys using `nokogiri`. But is it possible to get all keys and values inside the ParentNode `dynamically` and turn it into a hash?

Thank you.

> Note: Hash.from_xml wont work as am not using rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working sample:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<-EOS
<parentNode>
  <amount>12.0</amount>
  <authIdCode>999999</authIdCode>
  <currency>USD</currency>
</ parentNode>
EOS
document = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

hash = document.xpath("//parentNode/*").each_with_object({}) do |node, hash|
  hash[node.name] = node.text
end

p hash # => {"amount"=>"12.0", "authIdCode"=>"999999", "currency"=>"USD"}
```

It finds all the children of `parentNode`, uses the childs name as key, its text content as value.

Comment: I know this answers my question well.. But if any way to get a hash like this. `{"parentNode"=>{"amount"=>"12.0", "authIdCode"=>"999999", "currency"=>"USD"} }` ... So it gets the node regardless of the parentNode name??..There will always be one parent node though. So array is not needed. But the parent node name could change in some cases.

Comment: There will always be only one parent node that has child nodes? Are you sure? That would mean your root element is the parent node. If so, you could use `/*/*` as your XPath.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Hash[]`:

```
Hash[doc.search('parentNode/*').map{|n| [n.name, n.text]}]
#=> {"amount"=>"12.0", "authIdCode"=>"999999", "currency"=>"USD"}
```